Zeroes of subsequent derivatives
Suppose I have a function $f$ with parameters $b$ and $a$ given by
$$f(x) = A(x)b^2 + B(x)a + C(x)a^2 + D(x) + E, $$
where $A,B,C$ and $D$ are all unknown functions of $x$ and $E$ is a constant.
Will the equations $f(x) = 0$, $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x) = 0$ always be independent in the assumption that there is always a solution for each equation? Because this would imply that there is only a set of disconnected points $(x,a,b)$ that would satisfy these equations simultaneously.

Let $A=B=C=D=E=0$ then $f(x)=f'(x)=f''(x)=0$?

Are you assuming that there are solutions for $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$? No solutions would trivially be dependent.

Let $E=0$ with $A=B=D=x^3$ and $D=1$.
Then $f(x)=f'(x)=f''(x)=0$ gives constraints $\left(-\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}+a+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=x$, $x=0$ and $x=0$ respectively.
In this case, $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ are not independent.

I figured out that I can put more constraints on $f$, which invalidates this example. However, this is a solution to my asked question, so I accepted it.

I think your question could do with more context.
If you explain the motivation it would be easier to find a solution for the question you're trying to solve.
